# A tricky limit involving exponential integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lacunary-series

We define exponential integral according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definition_by_Ein

as

$$\text{Ei}_n(x) = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{t^n} dt$$

I'm trying to evaluate the limit of the sequence

$$ -\frac{i}{ \ln(2)}  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left[ \text{Ei}_{1- \frac{2i\pi}{\ln(2)}} \left( 2^{-n}   \right)-\text{Ei}_{1+\frac{2i\pi}{\ln(2)}} \left(  2^{-n} \right)  \right] $$

Where $n$ is evaluated over positive integers.

This approaches real number which is very close to the value $\frac{1}{\pi}$ but slightly less than it. (I have confirmed this experimentally).

### Work so far:

Attempting to evaluate this is as a limit of a function has been futile,

Since my inner limit results is an expression that doesn't converge:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[ \text{Ei}_{1- \frac{2i\pi}{\ln(2)}} \left( 2^{-n}   \right)-\text{Ei}_{1+\frac{2i\pi}{\ln(2)}} \left(  2^{-n} \right)  \right] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty, n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2^{-n}t}}{t^{1 - \frac{2i\pi}{\ln{2}}}} dt - \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2^{-n}t}}{t^{1 + \frac{2i\pi}{\ln{2}}}}dt $$

= $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[  \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2^{-n}t} \left( t^{1 + \frac{2i\pi}{\ln{2}}} - t^{1 - \frac{2i\pi}{\ln{2}}} \right)}{t^2} dt  \right]$$

$$ =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[  2i \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{-n} t} \frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{\ln 2} \ln t}{t} dt  \right]$$

At this point, "letting $n$ go to infinity" yields the divergent integral:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[ 2i \int_{1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{\ln 2} \ln t}{t} dt \right] $$

### Some Developments:

On Suggestion of Sangchul Lee I tried to apply integration by parts to our second to last term (dropping the $2i$ for now).

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[   \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{-n} t} \frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{\ln 2} \ln t}{t} dt  \right]$$

$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[ -\frac{\ln 2}{2\pi }e^{-2^{-n}t} \cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{\ln 2} \ln t \right)_{@[1,\infty]}   - 2^{-n} \frac{\ln 2}{2 \pi} \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{-n}t}\cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{\ln 2} \ln t \right) dt  \right] $$

We can now simplify the first term (taking the evaluation of infinity)

$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[ \frac{\ln 2}{2\pi }e^{-2^{-n}}   - 2^{-n} \frac{\ln 2}{2 \pi} \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{-n}t}\cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{\ln 2} \ln t \right) dt  \right] $$

And we see this becomes:

$$ = \frac{\ln 2}{2\pi } - \frac{\ln 2}{2 \pi } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[ 2^{-n}  \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-2^{-n}t}\cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{\ln 2} \ln t \right) dt  \right] $$

And, after consulting mathematica this reduces to:

$$ \frac{\ln 2}{2\pi } - \frac{\ln 2}{2 \pi } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}} \left[ \frac{1}{2}  \left(  \Gamma[1 - \frac{2i\pi}{\ln 2} , 2^{-n} ]   +  \Gamma[1 + \frac{2i\pi}{\ln 2} , 2^{-n} ] \right)\right]  $$

And that reduces pretty simply to:

$$ \frac{\ln 2}{2\pi } - \frac{\ln 2}{2 \pi }  \left[ \frac{1}{2}  \left(  \Gamma[1 - \frac{2i\pi}{\ln 2} , 0 ]   +  \Gamma[1 + \frac{2i\pi}{\ln 2} , 0 ] \right)\right]  $$

And Wolfram is able to verify that this indeed is the result I expect (once I multiply by $\frac{-i(2i)}{\ln 2}$ ) as it is within $10^{-6}$ of $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

My question remains: Is there a better closed form for this term?

Comment: Hint: Take integration by parts to the integral right before taking limit.

Comment: @SangchulLee so this somehow worked and numerically converges to the right thing, although I was hoping for a more beautiful closed form. It seems mathematica can't turn the Gamma terms into something elementary either, is there any further simplifications that can be made here in your opinion?

Comment: I will try to add an answer when I finish my dinner cooking, but the point is that the limit will be a kind of 'averaged version' (a.k.a. regularization) of the integral of sine, and the usual way of justifying this is to perform integration by parts so as to obtain better regularity control of the integrand. (To put simple, oscillatory behavior is not good to deal with, so averaging it out is often a better way to go.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\alpha = \frac{2\pi}{\log 2}$ for simplicity. Then we are interested in the limit of the following quantity

\begin{align*}
I_n
:= \frac{\operatorname{Ei}_{1 - i\alpha} (2^{-n}) - \operatorname{Ei}_{1 + i\alpha} (2^{-n})}{i\log 2}.
\end{align*}

Plugging the definition of $\operatorname{Ei}_s$ and taking integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= \frac{1}{i\log 2} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{i\alpha} - t^{-i\alpha}}{t}e^{-2^{-n}t} \, \mathrm{d}t
 = \frac{2}{\log 2} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\left( \alpha \log t \right)}{t}e^{-2^{-n}t} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&\hspace{1em}= \frac{e^{-2^{-n}}}{\pi} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{1}^{\infty} \cos\left( \alpha \log t \right) 2^{-n} e^{-2^{-n}t} \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Now apply the substitution $u = 2^{-n}t$ and notice that

$$\cos(\alpha \log t) = \cos(\alpha\log u + \alpha n\log 2) = \cos(\alpha \log u) $$

since $\alpha \log 2 = 2\pi$. Then

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \frac{e^{-2^{-n}}}{\pi} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{2^{-n}}^{\infty} \cos\left( \alpha \log u \right) e^{-u} \, \mathrm{d}u \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left( \alpha \log u \right) e^{-u} \, \mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}

By recalling that the gamma function is defined as $\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{s-1}e^{-u} \, \mathrm{d}u$, this reduces to

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n
&= \frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{\Gamma(1+i\alpha) + \Gamma(1-i\alpha)}{2\pi}
 = \frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Re}\left[ 1 - \Gamma(1+i\alpha) \right].
\end{align*}

But I am skeptical of this having an elementary closed form.